# functional calculus $\theta(1/f)=\theta(f)^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis

If $T\in B(H)$ is normal,and if $f\in C(S_p(T))$ is never zero,how to prove that the functional calculus $\theta$ for T satisfies

$$\theta(1/f)=\theta(f)^{-1}$$

Comment: I think if you have the correct definition of $\theta$, then this question should be very easy to answer.  So, what is $\theta$, formally?

Comment: You'll crucially need a normal operator. *(There's also a functional calculus in the realm of closed operators on Banach space but I guess that was not your intention, or?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional calculus is a homomorphism which sends $1$ to $Id$, so
$$
\theta(f)\theta(1/f)=\theta(1/f)\theta(f)=\theta(1)=Id.
$$